# Populating the first valid key_2 value for each key_1 in a BigQuery table based on future changes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table with date, key_1, and key_2. Is this example,key_2 will be -1 for all key_1 until it is assigned with some value in future. My requirement is to get the first non null(and not -1) key_2 value for key_1 and populate it for the remaining days until key_2 changes it's value.

In this example, key_2 is -1 from 1st March till 3rd March. But it will have a value(XYZ123) on 4th March. I have to populate with XYZ123 from March 1-3. And then the key_2 becomes PGQ123 on 7th March. It is not -1 or null, so I need to populate PGQ123 from March 7th onwards.

This is my input:

| date | key_1 | key_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | ABC | -1 |
| 02/01/2023 | ABC | -1 |
| 03/01/2023 | ABC | -1 |
| 04/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 05/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 06/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 07/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |
| 08/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |
| 09/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |

And this is the output I am expecting.

| date | key_1 | key_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 02/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 03/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 04/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 05/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 06/01/2023 | ABC | XYZ123 |
| 07/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |
| 08/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |
| 09/01/2023 | ABC | PGQ123 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
SELECT *,
       LAST_VALUE(
         IF(key_2 = '-1', NULL, key_2) IGNORE NULLS
       ) OVER w AS key_2_populated
  FROM sample_table 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY key_1 ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', date) DESC)
 ORDER BY date;
```

**Query results**

[image]